# Saving high scores in Android game - Shared Preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Recently I am developing a simple android game. For the scoring part, I have on many websites that shared preferences are best to save the high score. Now, what if I need to save high scores of different levels in my game? I wish to save top three scorers score for each level...

Comment: high score is for particular device or devices across the world?

Comment: Where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save your scores you can do something like this:

```
// prepare the data: put the String values of the scores of the first 3 users
// in one String array for each level
String[] firstLevelHighscores = new String[] { 
    firstUserLevel1Score, secondUserLevel1Score, thirdUserLevel1Score 
};
String[] secondLevelHighscores = new String[] { 
    firstUserLevel2Score, secondUserLevel2Score, thirdUserLevel2Score 
};
String[] thirdLevelHighscores = new String[] { 
    firstUserLevel3Score, secondUserLevel3Score, thirdUserLevel3Score 
};

// now save them in SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("LevelScores", 
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putStringSet("level1", firstLevelHighscores);
editor.putStringSet("level2", secondLevelHighscores);
editor.putStringSet("level3", thirdLevelHighscores);
```

Note that you can put even more user's scores into the String array. And if you need to save scores for more levels, you simply create more arrays.

To retrieve the saved data from SharedPreferences, you do it like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("LevelScores", 
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String[] firstLevelHighscores = sharedPref.getStringSet("level1", null);
String[] secondLevelHighscores = sharedPref.getStringSet("level2", null);
String[] thirdLevelHighscores = sharedPref.getStringSet("level3", null);
```

I assume you're able to convert `int` to `String` and vice versa. Hope it works for you this way.

Comment: thnx... It helped me out :)

Comment: Wanna except my answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

A lot of ways to save your scores to the `SharedPreference`. All depending on your style of implementation.

You can simply use the `putStringSet(key, String[])` where as the key will be the level and the String[] the 1ste, 2nd and 3th place.

Answer (score -1):

score setting

```
static final String[] LEVEL = {"level1","level2","level3"};

int bestScore1 = 100;
int bestScore2 = 90;
int bestScore3 = 80;

SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(LEVEL[0],Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

    editor.putInt("First", bestScore1);
    editor.putInt("Second", bestScore2);
    editor.putInt("Third", bestScore3);

    editor.commit();
```

but you need to count LEVEL's index

score getting

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(LEVEL[0], Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

    bestScore1 = sp.getInt("First", 0);
    bestScore2 = sp.getInt("Second", 0);
    bestScore3 = sp.getInt("Third", 0);
```

hmm.. but I think it is not best way for your question :<

Comment: In my first attempt I also thought in the same manner. But Terry has explained it very well.