# Retrieving a value from a text file

Tags: android, text-files, storage

I am building an application that contains a quiz. As soon as the user finishes the quiz, an activity is shown to the user where it calculates his total score as a `TextView`. What I want to achieve here is storing that TextView value shown to the user at the end of the quiz (containing the score), but also show that value store in another activity called where all the Highscores are showed. I believe I am storing the value, **but I cannot see it in my total scroe activity(not retrieving it)**This is initialized in both activities

```
    private final static String storeHighscores="storeHighscores.txt";
```

Summary after quiz activity.
the variable is called finalscore, int

```
finalScore = timeLeft * QuizActivity.correct;


            try {

                OutputStreamWriter out =    new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(storeHighscores, 0));

                out.write(finalScore);

                out.close();

                Toast.makeText(this, "The contents are saved in the file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            catch (Throwable t) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: "+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
```

TotaScore Activity

```
try {

        InputStream in = openFileInput(storeHighscores);

        if (in != null) {

        InputStreamReader tmp=new InputStreamReader(in);

        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(tmp);

        String str;

        StringBuilder buf=new StringBuilder();

        while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {

        buf.append(str);

        }

        in.close();

        easy.setText(buf.toString());

        }

        }
```

Not sure if I am using the right approach here, please free to suggest me how to achieve what I want, or alternatives for this approach.

Comment: You try to read a line from the file with `reader.readLine()` which returns a String. But there are no String lines in your file because you only wrote the four bytes of your integer to it. So write a String as line also. You can use `out.writeLine(String.valueOf(finalScore))`;

Comment: can you suggest me an implementation to get a general idea of what to do please?

Comment: All you have to do is use that line instead of the original write().

Comment: When replacing the out.writeLine()  method with the one suggested I get this error 'The method writeLine(String) is undefined for the type OutputStreamWriter'

Comment: Yes. You have to make your saving code more like the reading code. You used BufferedReader.readLine(). So the equivalent would be to add a BufferedWriter. That has the writeLine().

Comment: BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(storeHighscores));
    out.write(String.valueOf(finalScore));
    out.close();

Comment: is this the correct implementationj?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that using SharedPreferences would be better suited for this task.

See this post: [Saving high scores in Android game - Shared Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898490/saving-high-scores-in-android-game-shared-preferences)

Documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html