# What is the best way to save all high-scores of multiple levels in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, save, android-sharedpreferences, android-database

I am writing a [minesweeper](https://github.com/diptangsu/Minesweeper) application in android. It's got 3 difficulty modes and I want to save all the scores of all three difficulty modes. If I wanted to store just the high scores for all the modes, I could have done it with a `SharedPreferences object` but I want to store all the scores and display them to the player sorted by the time taken to solve or date on which it is solved.

I have thought of saving data in a file, or in a json file. I don't want to use SQLite databases because it's too much code.

I simply want to know if there is a better way to do this other than saving everything in a file (maybe in the assets).

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898490/saving-high-scores-in-android-game-shared-preferences) but I don't think the accepted solution can be used to solve my problem.

Comment: use room its less code than sqlite

Comment: Have you tried using Room from Android Architecture Components? It's a very helpful library to save or read data to/from SQLite Database.

Comment: I didn't know about that. I will check it out, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebase Database for that. The good thing with the database is that if you want your game to also display the leaderboards to others who are playing it, it shows in real-time. Simply add data when the game ends and filter the results based on the data. Hope this helped, heres a link to get you started [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/)

Comment: Ah! cool! I was waiting for an excuse to learn how to use Firebase.

Comment: Honestly it's not as hard as you would think a lot of tutorials out there and also alot of questions already asked about firebase